# Client Server communication in Java: how to distinguish between sockets

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, serversocket

I'm now processing a client-server communication in Java, by using Socket and ServerSocket objects. 
Once the server has been initialised, it puts on hold with new clients through the accept() method, from ServerSocket class; I immediately provide to put this socket in a client map on the server:
 - keys: ClientNode(Socket s, CommunicationChannels channels);
 - values: Info();
(CommunicationChannels contains ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream from socket; Info contains some information about client, as username, messages etc..).

Given that, at the very beginning, the socket does not have any other information on the client besides the socket itself, first insertion on the map is map.put(ClientNode, null). I will fill the field "value" afterwards.

Now, on Client class, I am going to initialise a Socket("127.0.0.1", 13001), namely with a loopback address and gate 13001. Once communication channels have been initialised, client connects to the server.

Once the client starts, he takes a remote copy of the server through RMI (stub) libraries and the server makes a register() method available: it would allow to use this method to write requested information (from the clients) on the map.

How can the client go back to the socket with which it has been registered on the server? Frankly speaking, I supposed that accept() method from ServerSocket could take the socket established on the startup client back to the server, namely with the new Socket("127.0.0.1", 13001), but it seems to me that this does not happen.

Here you can find parts of the code, so you can better understand what I'm talking about. I've already taken into account a few things that I will share with you in case of need.

```
public class Server implements Runnable, RemoteServices {
...
private Map<ClientNode, Info> map = new HashMap<ClientNode, Info>();
...
public void run() {
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket();
        while (true) {
            if (!ss.isBound()) {
                ss.bind(new InetSocketAddress(ipServer, port));
            }
            Socket client = ss.accept();
            CommunicationChannels channels = new CommunicationChannels(new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()), new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream()));
            map.put(new ClientNode(client, channels), null);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// RemoteServices implementa Remote e mette a disposizione register()
public void register(Info info) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO         
}


public class Client implements Runnable {
...
...

@Override
public void run() {

        Socket client = null;

        try {
            client = new Socket(ipServer, port);

                out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

                        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1");
            stub = (RemoteServices) registry.lookup("remoteObject");

                       Info info = new Info();
            info.setID(getID());
            info.setUsername("Giordano");

                        stub.register(info);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Spiacente: il server ha terminato l'esecuzione.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Remarks:

1. I have not included the code of some classes because I thought it was superfluous; for example the "info" class is just a series of "getter and setter" of some fields; the CommunicationChannels class represents communication channels of the client, taken directly from the socket, etc ..
2. The server, after the accept(), does not instantiate any thread to communicate with the client because communication has to come afterwards. However, if there was a way to solve my problem with a thread of communication I would find a way to fix it.
3. My question starts from the need to make interact 2 clients with a server without using more PCs; therefore all clients will have the IP loopback and therefore I cannot use the IP address as a discriminating between two sockets, otherwise I would have already solved it.
   In other words, I know that methods as socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() can help me to distinguish between two socket, but if I initialise two clients on the same PC I have to use loopback address and the method always returns "127.0.0.1".
4. The register() method is obviously incomplete even in the signature; once understood how to compare the server socket and client one through a Serializable discriminating object (like the hashcode()) probably I might put it in the arguments of the method, so you can easily make the comparison.

Finally, main() methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server("127.0.0.1", 13001);
        RemoteServices stub;
        try {
            stub = (RemoteServices) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.bind("remoteObject", stub);
            (new Thread(server)).start();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            System.err.println("Verificare l'apertura dei registri");
        } catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Server già attivo. Controllare che i registri siano chiusi correttamente.");
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {        Client client = new Client("127.0.0.1", 13001);
        new Thread(client).start();
    }
```

I really hope everything is clear and that you can help me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not think I follow. The client has to connect through a socket object. That object should contain all you need for further communication. Also, you can use Socket.getPort() to check which remote port you are actually connected to. Each client gets its own port.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was just I was looking for. So I can pass the Socket LocalPort on the client to the register() method; in this way I can make the equivalence between the socket.getPort() on the server side and the socket.getLocalPort() on the client side.
I'm sorry if I did not explain everything clearly, but the problem is solved. 
Thank you again.